# Slam gmapping tutorial troubleshooting

Tags: navigation, laserscan, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I'm following the map-building tutorial at http://www.ros.org/wiki/slam_gmapping/Tutorials/MappingFromLoggedData and I can get all the way through step 2 (hurray). Then when I enter:

```
 $ rosbag play aptLaserData.bag
```

which is the second part 1 of step 2, I get the error:

```
[ INFO] [1311128237.384522694]: Opening aptLaserData.bag

[FATAL] [1311128237.388682646]: Time is out of dual 32-bit range
```

My .bag file is indeed named aptLaserData.bag, but could you tell me what's causing the problem?

Thanks,
Khiya

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10651/slam-gmapping-tutorial-troubleshooting/) by [Khiya](https://answers.ros.org/users/669/khiya/) on ROS Answers with karma: 49 on 2011-07-19

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Khiya](https://answers.ros.org/users/669/khiya/) on 2011-07-28**:
Hi Brian, thanks for your patience! Please see my comment on Tim's post, below, for access to my aptLaserData.bag file.

**Comment by [Khiya](https://answers.ros.org/users/669/khiya/) on 2011-07-21**:
PS, could this problem have to do with the fact that I'm using a virtual machine running Ubuntu 10.10 from a 32-bit Windows machine running Vista?

**Comment by [Khiya](https://answers.ros.org/users/669/khiya/) on 2011-07-20**:
Brian, I can't find a way to upload a .bag file onto ROS answers. Unless you know of a better way to put my data online, I'm going to upload it to the repository for one of my other projects and make it available there.

**Comment by [Brian Gerkey](https://answers.ros.org/users/8/brian-gerkey/) on 2011-07-20**:
Another user reported the same problem, using the bag supplied with the tutorial: http://answers.ros.org/question/248/slam_gmapping-mappingfromloggeddata-out-of-dual-32.  I wasn't able to reproduce it.  Can you post your bag somewhere that we can try playing it back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

No activity in a month, closing.  In the future, please use the 'edit' feature to update the original question, or 'post a comment' feature in order to do followup so that it is more easy to track the state of the Q&A.

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2011-09-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0